# Electric dipole vs density gradient

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, physical-chemistry, molecules

Chemist here, so please excuse me for asking trivial stuff.

I am trying to represent the electron density of a molecule as a bunch of point charges.

One program that I use can calculate electron density at a grid of points in space, and also density gradient at the same grid of points (1st spatial derivative of the density, has 3 components).

The other program can take on input a grid of points, at which I can specify:

- point charge (1 value)
- electric dipole (3 values)
- higher multipoles

Now, I get the feeling that the gradient from the first code is the same thing as the dipole in the second code, cuz the dipole is essentially charge gradient.
On the other hand, my brain likes to cut corners, hence I need a physicist opinion.

How far am I off?

Comment: Electric dipole moment and charge density gradient don't have the same units. The dipole moment has units of C\*m while the gradient would have units of C\*m^-4

Comment: Yes, these are essentially the same thing. If you have an upward density gradient, you have more positive charge at the top of the cell, and more negative at the bottom, and that means the cell has an upward electric dipole moment. Of course, you have to make sure to convert units appropriately to relate them.

Comment: I see, thanks. Why would gradient be C*m^-4? Density's C*m^-3 divided by m? I can multiply by voxel volume (or whatever, gotta check), which would give me C/m, but where do I get another m^2?

Comment: @andrew.shyichuk When you take a gradient the derivatives d/dx, d/dy, and d/dz all have a differential of a spatial coordinate in the denominator so they have units of m^-1. That's where the dividing by m part comes from.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask in a more precise way. Electron density is probability per volume,  units are C m^-3. Derivative of that by 1 spatial coordinate would give Cm^-3 / m = Cm^-4. I can multiply that by voxel volume to get a gradient of probability at a point, or charge at a point (ish), which would be in the units of Cm^-1. How do I get from here to dipole moment which is Cm?

Or, do I get the whole thing wrong? What are the units of d\rho/dx?